# GraphicsMagick - cropping JPEG and converting to GIF results in black bar

Tags: image, crop, gif, graphicsmagick

I have a 1280x720 JPEG that I want to convert to a 720x720 GIF. When I simply crop without setting x & y offsets, it works fine:

```
gm convert -crop 720x720 images/one.jpg images/test.gif
```

But I want to keep the content centered/crop data off the edges. When I do that but do not convert to GIF, that works as well

```
gm convert -crop 720x720+280+0 images/one.jpg images/test.jpg
```

But when I both try to crop with offsets and convert to GIF, I wind up with a GIF that is properly centered and cropped, but there is a 280px black bar on the left side covering the content (or maybe it's just empty black space, as it is not bumping anything over):

```
gm convert -crop 720x720+280+0 images/one.jpg images/test.gif
```

I'm using GraphicsMagick v 1.3.20 in the bash shell on Mac running OSX 10.9.5

Comment: I don't know GM, only ImageMagick, but maybe try `repage` on your original JPEG in case there is some offset left over from otherr processing.

Comment: The `identify` command will tell you if you have an offset in any image.

Comment: Using it with the defaults of the cropped data like this `repage(720,720,0,0)` before writing out to file fixed it. Thanks. Post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know GM, only ImageMagick, but there at least, it is generally a good idea to use `repage` to remove any offsets that sneak in when cropping or changing geometry.

You should be able to see if there are any offsets by using the `identify` command-line tool:

```
identify image.png
image.png PNG 10x10 300x100+5+5 8-bit sRGB 2c 299B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Note the offset of `+5+5` above.

Comment: @Gregir: Why don't you *upvote* Mark's answer äs well?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: Done. (I was unaware you should upvote an answer in addition to accepting it. I thought the +15 rep for accepting implied the usefulness.)